# SpEasy-PostInstall failed

Tags: installation

When I ran SharePoint2010 EasySetup, it failed with error:
*New-SPSite : Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is properly configured, currently available, and that y
ou have the appropriate permissions to access the database before trying again.
At C:\SharePoint2010EasySetup\Labs\EasySetup\Source\SpEasy-PostInstall.ps1:132 char:11*

The reason is that $wApp as follow is empty. How to fix this? any suggestion?

```
$hostName = "www.contoso.com"
$siteName = "Contoso"
$wApp = Get-SPWebApplication

# create new site
Append-SpEasyLog ("`tCreating site: " + $hostName)
New-SPSite ("http://" + $hostName) -OwnerAlias $curUser.Name -HostHeaderWebApplication $wApp.Url -Name "Contoso" -Template $siteTemplate | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you running the PowerShell commands elevated (run as administrator)?
2. Do you have enough permissions to create the site collection? (farm admin or user with appropriate permissions, see Add-SPShellAdmin)

Comment: Yes, the current user is in local admin group.

Comment: When starting SP management shell cmdlet, I got the warning: The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.

Comment: Somehow easy setup couldn't create SharePoint Configuration/Content databases. After manually created them, easy setup runs without any issue.